# How To Display Now Watched Posts In Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to know how can I display a list with all the posts currently being viewed (on all open database connections)?

Comment: What do you mean by `display a list with all current post viewed`? Are people adding posts and you want to check which post has been read?

Comment: no... actually I want to show which posts are currently viewed by visitors in realtime...

Comment: Google analytics? What you are attempting is not easy. One way would be to use JS / jQuery that sends asynchronous calls to server every second while user is on page (or something), or have a DB table where you add / remove user ID and page ID each time user opens / leaves page.